# What additional axioms do we need to add so that Z3 can verify the satisfiability of programs with recurrences?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

As we [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915227/can-z3-check-the-satisfiability-of-formulas-that-contain-recursive-functions) Z3 has limitations with recurrences. Is there any way get the result for the following program? what will additional equation help z3 get the result?

```
    from z3 import *
    ackermann=Function('ackermann',IntSort(),IntSort(),IntSort())
    m=Int('m')
    n=Int('n')
    s=Solver()
    s.add(ForAll([n,m],Implies(And(n>=0,m>=0),ackermann(m,n) == If(m!=0,If(n!=0,ackermann(m - 1,ackermann(m,n - 1)),If(n==0,ackermann(m - 1,1),If(m==0,n + 1,0))),If(m==0,n + 1,0)))))
    s.add(n>=0)
    s.add(m>=0)
    s.add(Not(Implies(ackermann(m,n)>=0,ackermann(m+1,0)>=0)))
    s.check()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z3 will not try to do anything by induction for you, but (as Levent Erkok mentioned) you can give it the induction hypothesis and have it check that the result follows.

This works on your example as follows.

```
(declare-fun ackermann (Int Int) Int)

(assert (forall ((m Int) (n Int))
                (= (ackermann m n)
                   (ite (= m 0) (+ n 1)
                        (ite (= n 0) (ackermann (- m 1) 1)
                             (ackermann (- m 1) (ackermann m (- n 1))))))))

(declare-const m Int)
(declare-const n Int)

(assert (>= m 0))
(assert (>= n 0))

; Here's the induction hypothesis
(assert (forall ((ihm Int) (ihn Int))
                (=> (and (<= 0 ihm) (<= 0 ihn)
                         (or (< ihm m) (and (= ihm m) (< ihn n))))
                    (>= (ackermann ihm ihn) 0))))

(assert (not (>= (ackermann m n) 0)))
(check-sat) ; reports unsat as desired
```

Answer (score 3):

With a nested recursive definition like Ackermann's function, I don't think there's much you can do to convince Z3 (or any other SMT solver) to actually do any interesting proofs. Such properties will require clever inductive arguments, and an SMT solver is just not the right tool for this sort of verification. A theorem prover like Isabelle, HOL, Coq, ... is the better choice here.

Having said that, the basic approach to establishing recursive function properties in SMT is to literally code up the inductive hypothesis as a quantified axiom, and arrange for the property you want proven to precisely line up with that axiom when the e-matching engine kicks in so it can instantiate the quantifiers "correctly." I'm putting the word *correctly* in quotes here, because the matching engine will go ahead and keep instantiating the axiom in unproductive ways especially for a function like Ackermann's. Theorem provers, on the other hand, precisely give you control over the proof structure so you can explicitly guide the prover through the proof-search space.

Here's an example you can look at: [list concat in z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473042/list-concat-in-z3) which is doing an inductive proof of a much simpler inductive property than you are targeting, using the SMT-Lib interface. While it won't be easy to extend it to handle your particular example, it might provide some insight into how to go about it.

In the particular case of Z3, you can also utilize its fixed-point reasoning engine using the PDR algorithm to answer queries about certain recursive functions. See http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/fixedpoints#h22 for an example that shows how to model McCarthy's famous 91 function as an interesting case study.